# Not sure if the match function is used correctly or there is other mistakes in this function in r

Tags: r, function

I am trying to apply a function to calculate some variables. This is how my output should look like:

[image]

In column D, in red, is the way column C should be calculated. This is why I used the function `match`. The number to substract (1000) should be the one at the first R occurrence from column A. I never used `match` before so maybe there is something wrong here or anywhere else in my function.

This is what I did:

```
library(dplyr)
p_hi <- 0.472              
rate_increase_hi <- 1.058*10^(-3)  

seed.mass.fraction.f<-function(stage, p_hi, rate_increase_hi, c_total_biomass, c_biomass_during_rep){

 seed.mass.fraction <- 0  
 if(stage == "V") {rate_increase_hi = 0}
  if(stage == "R") {rate_increase_hi = rate_increase_hi}
  
  if(stage == "V") {c_biomass_during_rep = 0}
  if(stage == "R") {c_biomass_during_rep = c_total_biomass - c_total_biomass(match("R", stage))}
  
  if(seed.mass.fraction < p_hi)  {seed.mass.fraction = rate_increase_hi * c_biomass_during_rep}
  if(seed.mass.fraction >= p_hi) {seed.mass.fraction = p_hi}
  
  return(seed.mass.fraction)
  
}

c_total_biomass <- seq(0, 1600, 100)
stage <- c(rep("V", 10), rep("R", 7))
data.smf<- data.frame(cbind(stage, c_total_biomass)) %>%
  mutate(c_total_biomass = as.numeric(c_total_biomass)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(smf = seed.mass.fraction.f(stage, p_hi, rate_increase_hi, c_total_biomass, c_biomass_during_rep)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `smf`.
i `smf = seed.mass.fraction.f(...)`.
x could not find function "c_total_biomass"
i The error occurred in row 11.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237390/discussion-on-question-by-giuseppe-petri-not-sure-if-the-match-function-is-used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `seed.mass.fraction` is not passed as an input argument and it should be found from the original data, which it couldn't.  An option is to use `cur_data_all()` to get the data and subset the column

```
 seed.mass.fraction.f<-function(stage, p_hi, rate_increase_hi, c_total_biomass, c_biomass_during_rep){

 dat <- cur_data_all()
 c_total_biomass <- dat[["c_total_biomass"]]
 stage <- dat[["stage"]]
  first_c_total_biomass <- dat[["first_c_total_biomass"]]
 
  seed.mass.fraction <- 0
  if(stage == "V") {rate_increase_hi = 0}
  if(stage == "R") {rate_increase_hi = rate_increase_hi}
  
  if(stage == "V") {c_biomass_during_rep = 0}
  if(stage == "R") {c_biomass_during_rep = c_total_biomass - first_c_total_biomass}
  
  if(seed.mass.fraction < p_hi)  {seed.mass.fraction = rate_increase_hi * c_biomass_during_rep}
  if(seed.mass.fraction >= p_hi) {seed.mass.fraction = p_hi}
  
  return(seed.mass.fraction)
  
}
```

-testing

```
data.frame(stage, c_total_biomass) %>% 
    mutate(first_c_total_biomass = c_total_biomass[stage == "R"][1]) %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(smf = seed.mass.fraction.f(stage, p_hi, rate_increase_hi,
     c_total_biomass, c_biomass_during_rep)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
   stage c_total_biomass   smf
   <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
 1 V                   0 0    
 2 V                 100 0    
 3 V                 200 0    
 4 V                 300 0    
 5 V                 400 0    
 6 V                 500 0    
 7 V                 600 0    
 8 V                 700 0    
 9 V                 800 0    
10 V                 900 0    
11 R                1000 0    
12 R                1100 0.106
13 R                1200 0.212
14 R                1300 0.317
15 R                1400 0.423
16 R                1500 0.472
17 R                1600 0.472
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked perfectly. Is there any way to make it work with this ```mutate(first_c_total_biomass = c_total_biomass[stage == "R"][1]) ``` somehow within the function? What I really need is the function to be fully functional independent from the testing phase.

Comment: @GiuseppePetri The issue with that is you are calling the function after `rowwise` and the data is not an argument.  So, the `cur_data_all`, gets the row data and not the whole column.  Otherwise, you may need a data argumnet as input into function and then it is easier

Comment: I used ```rowwise``` because I didn't know better to get this thing tested. I don't want to take more of your time. I am not sure how to input a data argument in the function. I'll explore a bit and will post another question if needed. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: @GiuseppePetri is there any issue in adding one more parameter as input i.e. `data` in the function, and then it becomes easier

Comment: What i meant is that `seed.mass.fraction.f<-function(data, stage, p_hi, rate_increase_hi, c_total_biomass, c_biomass_during_rep) {first_c_total_biomass = with(data, c_total_biomass[stage == "R"][1])`

Comment: I don't think this should be an issue

Comment: @GiuseppePetri then just change the function by adding the `data` as argument and create the `first_c_total_biomass` as  inthe comments

Comment: Sorry, but where is ```data``` coming from?

Comment: @GiuseppePetri so, when you call the function in `mutate`, it would be ` mutate(smf = seed.mass.fraction.f(., stage, p_hi, rate_increase_hi,
     c_total_biomass, c_biomass_during_rep))` i.e. `.` is the data